# I'm not able to ask questions -- is it my mistake or a system error?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban, limits

I asked a question on SO three days ago, and I got three downvotes. From that day, I have been unable to ask questions. Then I studied this [Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998) question; I thought answering questions and getting only upvotes would solve the problem. So I answered some questions, and I got 150 reputation, but I am still unable to ask questions. What do I have to do now?

Comment: This could be an artifact of down votes on questions not costing the voter, I'm flagging this for developer attention. I'm not _sure_, hence flagging.

Comment: Don't forget to edit your existing questions to improve those too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The long and the short answer is, I don't know. The stackoverflow team haven't released any information regarding precisely what you have to do (if anything!) to be permitted to ask questions again. (*One thing not to do is create another account. This will be found out. Don't do it.*)

Having looked at your questions, to be frank, they're not very good. Let me clarify that, **the community doesn't appear to think they're very good**. Out of 33 questions, you've had 7 up-votes and 3 down-votes. That's a net total of 4 up-votes across 33 questions, or 0.12 up-votes per question asked. **That is very low**. Taking [how to print a variable into a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386594/how-to-print-a-variable-into-a-text-box) as an example:

*(I'm aware that English is probably not your first language, and trust me, your english is better than my French/German/Spanish/etc!)*

- The title: Take the time to capitalise appropriately, `How` instead of `how` to start.
- The title: A question mark on the end wouldn't hurt, you have after all phrased it as a question.
- Don't put a salutation in questions, you should be well aware, after having asked that many questions that they're generally "not wanted" on stackoverflow, yet on your more recent question "[Doubt in extract a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081064/doubt-in-extract-a-string)" you've again added one.
- Take some time to get your spelling right. In "Doubt in extract a string" your salutation says "hi fiends", I'd suggest you probably meant "hi friends".
- **SHOW SOME CODE**. Yes, that's in bold and ALL CAPITALS. There's generally no reason not to show some code. Don't expect people to answer your questions by writing your code for you. **Try to write the code and then ask questions when you encounter problems**.

Now for some specifics:

> hi all I have a one variable. i want to print that varible into a text box. how to do this.

1. Remove the "hi all"
2. Capitalise appropriately. I'm well aware that this can be very difficult to get right when English isn't your first language. A simple rule of thumb:

   1. Anything after a `.` should have the first letter capitalised
   2. The letter `I` should always be capitalised when it's on its own
3. Explain a bit more; what data-type is the variable? What does it contain?
4. Show what you've tried.

**For example:**

---

I have a variable, called `myData` of type `NSString*`. It contains the text `SOME TEXT`. I want to have the text in myData displayed in a text box, but can't get it to work. I've tried this:

```
NSString* myData  = @"SOME TEXT";
UITextView* myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe];
myTextView.text = @"";
```

How can I solve this?

---

In other words:

1. Improve some of your existing questions, they may still gain up-votes as editing them will push them back onto the first page. Up-votes **will** help you be enabled to ask questions again.
2. Continue providing high quality answers.
3. If this all fails, consider emailing `team@stackoverflow.com` and asking if they can consider reversing the ban.

**The fact that you've taken the time to answer questions to try and improve your standing on the site is favourable, in my opinion** =)

Comment: Wow very nice answer! One nitpick about "creating another account, that will be found out"... It's not that it will be found out... It will just not work, as the ban is on ip-level.

Comment: +1. It's important that, as well as improving your actions on the site going forward, you also take the time to revisit and fix your old mistakes.  They are going to be around for a long time, after all.

Comment: @fretje - Well, it's simpler to phrase it that way, otherwise anyone reading could think "I'll create another account on another PC, with a different IP address". Either you'll be found out at **the point of account creation**, or further down the line when you forget and try to use the account from the banned IP. I was oversimplifying a touch =)